# Generate sql queries at run time and bind data to gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I made a website in asp.net. In it i have used sqldatasource objects or ado.net to bind data to gridview and display it to user.

Now the problem is that i want to make all of this dynamic, i.e. on the basis of user credentials(user name/password entered on login page) i want to display data from corresponding tables which can have different columns.

As long as columns of all the table were same, i solved this problem by using dynamic sql, i passed table name at run on the basis of user credentials but now the table columns will vary.

Please help.

Comment: Have you had a look at Entity Framework, Linq to Sql, or other ORMs?

Comment: Mate can u come up with some links that can help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links for you, you can easily find more using your choice of search engine.

[C# .Net L2S Tutorial [Scott Gu's]](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

[C# .Net Entity Framework 4.1 Video Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134816)

[VB .Net L2S Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-vb)

[VB (and C#) Entity Framework Tutorial](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Tutorial_EF.html)

I hope that gets you started.